# How would I turn my Raspberry Pi 1 and my two old loudspeakers into a "dumb sound outputter"?

Tags: audio

I have major issues sleeping. Both obnoxious neighbours/passer-bys, and total silence, bother me. I keep a floor fan on 24/7 for both the cooling and the "white noise" resulting from it, masking the noises to a very small extent and somewhat giving me the illusion of "wind blowing outdoors" or something.

I can't keep my normal computer on when I'm asleep, but it has no loudspeakers anyway. I have an old RPI v1 and loudspeakers. I would like to turn them into a little "dumb sound outputter". That is, I want to simply place a sound file (such as a 10-hour FLAC/OGG of recorded rain) on the flash card, stick it into the RPI, hook the loudspeakers up, plug in the power, and just have it loop that sound file over and over again.

It would have no network access or anything. If possible, I would like to avoid having a whole Linux installed on it, since it just complicates things and makes it take forever to start. Is there some kind of "dedicated OS" for this specific task? Just outputting and looping the sound file found on the card and nothing else?

Comment: if you cannot use the speakers with a PC, then you cannot use them with the RPi either

Answer (score 0):

Excellent idea! You'll need an amplifier of some sort to drive the speakers... I have a v.4 rpi and the output from the 1/8" port is adequate for "A/V" (haven't tried but earbuds likely would work) but NOT speakers.  I'm trying to think of an inexpensive solution for your amplifier idea; I'd start with a trip to GoodWill or Salvation Army in search of a small Receiver/Amplifier that someone no longer needed.  You'll likely also need a 1/8" to stereo cable adapter since not many old tech amps had 1/8" input, only stereo Red and White ports for input.

Comment: The "red and white ports" are called *RCA connectors*, if you need to look for a cable.  Also, technically there was once a 1/8" jack in use but it is not quite the same as 3.5mm, the latter will actually not fit into the former (although it doesn't matter now as you are very unlikely to see actual 1/8th jacks).